# Wait to notify subscribers in ReactiveCocoa until code finishes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

With ReactiveCocoa and KVO, if you subscribe to something, it will immediately notify the subscribers when you change the value you're binding to. Let's say my state depends on user.firstName and user.lastName:

```
RAC(self.fullName) = [RACSignal 
    combineLatest:@[RACAble(self.firstName), RACAble(self.lastName)]
    reduce:^(NSString* firstName, NSString* lastName) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    }];

self.firstName = @"Bob";
self.lastName  = @"Wilson";
self.firstName = @"Amy";
self.lastName  = @"Johnson";

// ... 

- (void)setFullName:(NSString*)fullName
{
    NSLog(@"FULL NAME %@", fullName);
    // Bob Wilson
    // Amy Wilson
    // Amy Johnson
}
```

So long as both variables are set, it calls setFullName each time I change *either* `firstName` or `lastName`.

I would like it to wait until the changes have "settled" to call full name, so, if I set the values in the same function like that, it calls `setFullName` once with the final values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `combineLatest:` you can use `zip:`. That will wait for all input signals to send a value. This way the subscriber will be notified only if the `firstName`, `lastName` setting has happened.

If this is not acceptable, and it is possible that either only `firstName` or `lastName` will change, then you can put `throttle:` to the output of the `combineLatest:`. This way if several changes happen in the throttling time, then only the last value will be sent to the subscribers.

Side note: if you can construct the `fullName` based on current values, then why store it in a property? You may use it a signal.

Comment: The example was just contrived to show the problem, it's usually that I want to update some view state based on several properties

Comment: I think maybe the biggest problem is I can't figure out where to FIND stuff like that? I'm looking all over the ReactiveCocoa github page and I can't find `throttle:` documented anywhere. Where is it?

Comment: When in doubt, use the find function. `throttle:` is in the RACSignal+Operations category. The documentation is in the header file. Regarding the documentation: yes, it's a little hard to conceive at first and usually becomes meaningful only after you worked quite a bit with it. When you can't find what you search for in the source code, or in the wiki, come to SO, ask a question or submit an issue to the project repo. These guys provide you with excellent info any time you ask. Truly amazing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I got thrown because so much functionality is in categories. I normally have no problem reading header files for documentation, but Command-clicking into RACSignal didn't show me all the options.